# Crop the white margins of text-based multi-page PDF document and convert it to image-based PDF document

Tags: pdf, kindle, calibre

I want convert an electronic book for Kindle. I tried to convert large, two languages text-based PDF ebook with complex formatting styles and images into AZW3 book for Kindle using Calibre, and also tried amazon service, but conversion results poor quality with multiple errors. I can no convert PDF ebook into plain text which best suits for kindle, because ebook contains multiple formatting styles, programming code and images.

What is the best way automatically crop the white margins of text-based multi-page PDF document and convert it to image-based PDF document, resized to fit 600 x 800 pixels?

Comment: What is your level of programming ability? There are a variety of libraries and languages that can accomplish this, but they all require familiarity with the command-line and basic programming.

Comment: I mean use some freeware utility for End-User.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several tools exists for this kind of job:

- http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/
- http://code.google.com/p/papercrop/
- http://briss.sourceforge.net/
- https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/

I'd check them out before trying to reinvent the wheel. Or you had not meant programming a new solution but then your question is off topic on this site, see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help).